# How can I create a layer over React Native navigation tabs?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to create a navigation dropdown menu. Outside of that menu, I want to create a layer that closes the menu when the user clicks on it. When I create this layer the color of it doesn't cover the bottom navigation tabs and I can't find any way to do it.

The layer doesn't cover the bottom tabs
[image]

Comment: What navigation library are you using for the bottom navigation tabs?

Comment: I use react-navigation. (react-navigation/bottom-tab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could navigate to a modal screen with a header and the menu list and set a transparent card style so you can have a overlay that can navigate back, and a different animation than the default slide:

- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal
- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#cardstyle
- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#animationenabled

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using the React Native Modal component?  https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal

It could be used to render the menu above other components and supports an `onRequestClose` prop.

```
<Modal
        animationType="fade"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
        }}
      >
```